# JavaScript transitive equality

Tags: javascript, equality

Learning JavaScript and found that given the expression below, it evaluates to true when given this: `transitive([1], 1, {toString:_=>'1'});`

I don't understand why.

it makes sense that the y and z are equal but how can the x and y be equal if the x and z are not equal?

```
function transitive(x,y,z) {
     return x && x == y && y == z && x != z;
}
```

Comment: Use the strict equality operator, `===` which will check both the type and the value as opposed to just the value.

Comment: I made a [little tool](https://nem035.github.io/js-equality-algorithms/), it might help. The tool shows you how the engine actually evaluates `==` and `===`,  (including how it does the coercion ) so you can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: @nem035 great tool. really helpful for understanding what is happening in an equality checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript there is a concept of "truthiness" and "falsyness". Values like `1` and `'1'` are equal when compared with a loose comparison operator like `==`, but are not strictly equal using a strict equality operator like `===`.

The object is equal to `1` because JavaScript uses type coercion to convert the object to a comparable value to a primitive. It does this by calling the `.toString()` method of the object, which returns `'1'` and as we learned above is truthy, as is `1`, so they are considered equal when using `==`.

This will probably be relevant:  [MDN: Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

It is best/common practice in JavaScript to always use `===` and `!==` in place of `==` and `!=`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I added a more direct answer. Thanks for pointing out that my answer wasn't adequate as it was.

Comment: @TW80000 so since x and z are not primitive when using type coercion they are not equal ? but since y is primitive then that comparison is ?

Comment: Type coercion is not used (afaik) if none of the elements being compared are primitive. For example: `[] == []` is `false`, even though `[].toString() == [].toString()` is `true`.

Comment: So since neither `x` nor `z` are primitive, they are not coerced into primitives and therefore are obviously not equal. If they were coerced they would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The "loose" [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) in javascript (`==`) is *not* transitive. This is primarily a result of type coercion that occurs before comparison. `==` uses javascript's "[abstract equality](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)" algorithm which *roughly* boils down to these steps. Successive coercions can occur.

1. If one operand is a primitive and another is an object (including an array), a [not so simple algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-toprimitive) is used to coerce the object to a primitive, which can involve (among other things) the object's `toString`, `valueOf`, or `[Symbol.toPrimitive]` method.
2. Booleans are coerced to numbers.
3. If one operand is a number and the other is a string, the string is coerced to a number.
4. `null` and `undefined` are considered equal to themselves and eachother and nothing else. Otherwise a [strict equality comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) is performed.

That's a lot of complexity packed into a single operator and the result is a very wiggly concept of equality with a bunch of gotchas.

```js
// Is an empty array truthy or falsey?
[] == false;       // -> true, so [] is falsey?
[] ? true : false; // -> true, so [] is truthy?

// Another case of intransitivity:
false == "0"  // -> true
false == []   // -> true
"0" == []     // -> false

// Not super consistent
123 == "123"       // -> true
123 == [123]       // -> true
true == "true"     // -> false
true == [true]     // -> false
"true" == [true]   // -> true
true == ["1"]      // -> true
```

Applying these coercion rules to your example:

```
[1] == 1 
// Object is coerced to primitive, in this case via toString
"1" == 1
// String is coerced to number
1 == 1
/* true */
```

```
1 == {toString:_=>'1'}
// Object is coerced to primitive, in this case via toString
1 == "1"
// String is coerced to number
1 == 1
/* true */
```

```
[1] == {toString:_=>'1'}
// Since neither value is a primitive, no coercion occurs. 
// Reference equality is checked instead.
/* false */
```

Just about the only reason I use `==` is to check if a value is either `null` *or* `undefined` with a single comparison. Otherwise I stick with `===` which is much easier to reason about.